# Faster way to build app for testing

Tags: ios, archive

I have an ios app that needs to be regularly tested.
It has over 500 source files, and it take like 5 minutes to compile it all.

Archiving it takes over 15 minutes

creating a distribution another 2 minutes

this whole process is very painful 30 minutes , and when i need tobuild it once every 10 minutes, this is even more painful

is there a more pain free method of doing this ?

Comment: +1 for asking a thing every ios dev face but never ask. :)

Comment: I don't think an App needs to re-build for so frequent testing, until it has lots of bugs.. Better to plan testing.. As we don't have any other option to do it, or if its inhouse testing you can better connect multiple devices and install directly..

Comment: boss has meetings to market app, fixing bugs on the fly ... :(

Comment: install directly not possible, boss is 150kms away from me atm

Comment: I am wondering what is your app type? I have built 2 complex projects on my own but the source files are no where near 500.

Comment: Its an app that contains a bunch of libraries, and since libraries are not exactly atomic (1 task for 1 library), i get a bunch of redundant files from the libraries that i include

Comment: plus it has 15 screens, with over 50 nibs and its localized in 6 languages (the nibs are localized, not the strings)

Comment: That's weird I'm currently working on a project with 600 source files and 8 libraries. It takes 30 seconds to compile for development.....2 minutes for release builds (compiling all 3 architectures). Archiving takes about the same as compiling release builds. Creating a distribution less than a minute. This is on a machine with an SSD though. What kind of machine are you using?

Comment: Macbook Pro , no SSD, 4GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

Two words. [Continuous Integration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/000-About_Continuous_Integration/about_continuous_integration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292).

Apple introduced Bots for Xcode 5. Which will do automation of build deployments. But you need to set those things which at first can take more time.

Also you can make your work much simpler with Testflight. [Try this](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/23/ci-with-jenkins-for-ios-apps-build-distribution-via-testflightapp-tutorial/)

Comment: apple purchased testflight, and so i can't use it ,because i didnt register before february 2014

Comment: Yes i went through the same problem. :[